# How do I modify the auto-generated menu and "About" box of Mac LAF in Java?

Tags: java, windows, macos, menubar

[image]

The screenshot shows on the menu bar an apple (which is the system menu) the app menu "GSPro" which has the about and quit items, the ss also shows how the built in about box looks, this can be modified to look more professional and have icons/revs/author etc.
That's the bits I'm having trouble finding info on and good examples.
The file menu onwards is what my app generates and will look the same in windows so I know I would have to do windows menus slightly differently from mac stuff.

On the mac this is known as laf (look and feel).

My code snip is as follows, no handlers yet but just testing how it shows...

```
    public class GSPro {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.setProperty("apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar", "true");

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setExtendedState(frame.getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setTitle("GSPro");

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

    JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
    menuBar.add(file);
    JMenu edit = new JMenu("Edit");
    menuBar.add(edit);
    JMenuItem  exit = new JMenuItem("New");
    file.add(exit);
    JMenuItem open = new JMenuItem("Open");
    file.add(open);
    file.addSeparator();
    JMenuItem close = new JMenuItem("Close");
    file.add(close);
    file.addSeparator();
    JMenuItem save = new JMenuItem("Save");
    file.add(save);
    JMenuItem saveas = new JMenuItem("Save As...");
    file.add(saveas);

    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
}
```

}

Comment: Java is cross-platform, the menus you create for Windows and Mac are the same. If this is at all what you mean.

Comment: Thanks, I have done lots of android dev so java I can get things working but I'm starting a project I want to look professional on mac and windows, I have only just got a macbook and I notice that there is an apple menu with "about" and 'quit" then my programmed menu, I would like to modify the about box to look better but can't find much more info than enabling the look and feel or changing the title, so I sort of understand some things but others seem specific to the systems in use... Hope I'm making sense, I come from a low level background so don't have the "language" around the "subject"

Comment: No one knows what your about box looks like or what you want it to look like unless you post code and \ or images. I can't give you help on how `to modify the about box to look better` out of thin air.

Comment: I tried to add some edits/images to try show what I mean but I have no  reputation, I'll try put up on a page and post...

Comment: You show one thing in the code and another in the screenshot.  You still don't specify what you want to achieve. Edit the question to show "What is the question and what is the relevant code?".

Comment: Maybe I understand. You want to modify the auto-generated code of the MAC LAF?

Comment: That sounds about right but I can't find where or if it is possible in eclipse (which I prefer to use), most of the info I have found uses Xcode and objective c but I want to use java for the cross platform aspect...

Comment: Sorry I have just noticed your previous answer saying the code and screenshot don't seem to match but that is what I see on my mac for that code, I would like to add to/mod the about box that apple generates for the system menu bar for my app. The rest of the menu is created by me and I understand that I need to add about and quit for the windows version. I would like to change the icon and version number presented by the apple system menu for my app and maybe add some fields like author and copyright etc...

Comment: Try reading [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/07-NativePlatformIntegration/NativePlatformIntegration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001909-211867-BCIBDHFJ) or [this](http://test.javaranch.com/ulf/apple-java-tech-notes/Tech%20Notes/tn2042.html#Section2_3), they are very similar. See if it helps, you need to use Apple's libraries it seems.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the icon and version information, it comes from the [application bundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/corefoundation/conceptual/cfbundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html) [properties file](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009254-SW1) (Info.plist).  Create an application bundle, complete with icon and version properties and you'll see the About dialog display this info.

You might be better off making your own custom About dialog though.  I've never seen an application that used the default one as you screen captured above.  Additionally, this would allow you to use the same About dialog across platforms.  Here's how you would do it on OS X:

```
public class Test implements com.apple.eawt.AboutHandler {

    public Test() {
        // comment these two lines to see the default About dialog
        com.apple.eawt.Application app = com.apple.eawt.Application.getApplication();
        app.setAboutHandler(this);

        JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();
        myFrame.setSize(200, 200);
        myFrame.setVisible(true);
    }



    @Override
    public void handleAbout(com.apple.eawt.AppEvent.AboutEvent ae) {
        JFrame aboutFrame = new JFrame();
        aboutFrame.setSize(200, 200);
        aboutFrame.add(new JLabel("About"));
        aboutFrame.pack();
        aboutFrame.setVisible(true);
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that, I got it working in eclipse but not right away. It gave me access restrictions on libs but I messed around till it worked. (Can't really remember what I did! I was randomly pressing buttons!) It all seems very intricate for what I believed was write for anything in one place but I will keep learning... Thanks again everyone